# Why Are Some Characters Incapable of Being Pulled From Linux/Bash Environment Variables Into PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, environment-variables, openssh

I'll try to make this as short as possible without making it completely unreadable.

I'm storing encrypted data-sets in my database using PHP's openssl implementation.

Here's something similar to what I'm doing:

```
$pw = 'nobody loves you like I do.';
$cm = 'aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha256';
$c_key = '-$k���۱�d��o��ּ)2�"�C�!{���"�pO�⌧Ӝ�A��)mL�ڡ��i����OP753D8⮩eÒ98u07ף�11�u�e';
$iv = '�w�[(32';
$sslpw = openssl_encrypt($pw, $cm, $c_key, $options=0, $iv);
```

The values I'm populating `$c_key` and `$iv` with were all generated using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

So, thinking there'd be no issue here, I made a small file with all such values to be sourced into environment variables like so:

```
export PAXYZ_C_KEY='-$k���۱�d��o��ּ)2�"�C�!{���"�pO�⌧Ӝ�A��)mL�ڡ��i����OP753D8⮩eÒ98u07ף�11�u�e';
export PAXYZ_C_IV='�w�[(32'
```

However, after I source the file, and read them into my PHP script, I lose a good 50% of each string even though they're string literals.

However, if I set the env var directly via command line, it sets just fine. The issue is sticking it in a file and setting it within the file. I don't even know why this would make a difference, but it does.

If I keep everything strictly PHP, there are no issues with any of these characters.

At what level can I even diagnose this? It doesn't seem to matter whether I copy and paste into the terminal or an editor - the result is the same. But really, this is about where my expertise comes to a grinding halt.

Unfortunately, I've already done much encrypting with my current set of keys - so I'm not too hot on re-encrypting everything if I don't have to.

Comment: I'd base64_encode this data for use in the `.env` file, and have the app base64_decode it.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables are C strings, and as such cannot contain null bytes. Random data, like the output of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, will often contain null bytes. You will need to encode the output of these functions in a way that guarantees that they will not contain null bytes; one straightforward way of doing so will be to use `base64_encode()` before placing them into environment variables.